# Create unique index error on CosmosDB (Mongo API)

Tags: mongodb, indexing, unique

I am trying to create an unique index on some of the collections on our CosmosDB. Per MS document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing : Unique indexes can be created only when the collection is empty (contains no documents).

So I cleanup all the data on the collection, however I was encountering the error, the message was :

Error=13, Details='Response status code does not indicate success: Forbidden (403); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: xxx, Reason: (Message: {"serializedCollection":"{"Errors":["The unique index cannot be modified. To change the unique index, remove the collection and re-create a new one."]}","serializedOffer":"","serializedPartitionKeyRanges":[],"serializedPartitions":[],"collectionRemoteStorageSecurityIdentifier":"xxx","collectionChildResourceNameLimitInBytes":-1,"collectionChildResourceContentLengthLimitInKB":-1,"uniqueIndexNameEncodingMode":0,"uniqueIndexReIndexingState":0}
ActivityId: xxx, Request URI: /apps/xxx/xxx/partitions/xxx/replicas/xx, RequestStats:
RequestStartTime: 2020-12-02T23:25:04.2104773Z, RequestEndTime: 2020-12-02T23:25:04.2204125Z,  Number of regions attempted:1
ResponseTime: 2020-12-02T23:25:04.2204125Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.0.0.29:11000/apps/xxx/services/xx/partitions/xx/replicas/xx, LSN: 41, GlobalCommittedLsn: 41, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 403, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1.57, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#41, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Collection, OperationType: Replace
, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0, Please see CosmosDiagnostics, Windows/10.0.17763 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.3.2);

I then tried to add only the field name , then it was throwing errors like:

Cannot create unique index when collection contains documents

We are using CosomosDB which supports Mongodb 3.6. I was using the command:
db.CollectName.createIndex({"fieldname" : 1}, {"unique" : true } )

Any ideas why I am getting the errors?

Thanks,

Comment: `db.getCollectionInfos({name:"CollectName"})` and paste output

Comment: [
    {
        "name" : "CollectionName",
        "type" : "collection",
        "options" : {}
    }
]

Comment: Using the same command I had no errors to create the unique index on my local mongodb. But it doesn't work for CosmosDB. The collection is limited size with 20GB so no shard key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what happened but it suddenly starts to work now. So the step is to clean out the data in the collection. Run the script to add the unique index and then load the data back. I am using Robo 3t to connect to the CosmosDB and run all the commands through Robo3T command line.

Comment: ridiculous. This seems like something cosmos should be able to support automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In Cosmos DB for MongoDB, you cannot create a unique index if there are already documents in the collection. Quote from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/indexing#migrate-collections-with-indexes):

> Currently, you can only create unique indexes when the collection contains no documents. Popular MongoDB migration tools try to create the unique indexes after importing the data. To circumvent this issue, you can manually create the corresponding collections and unique indexes instead of allowing the migration tool to try.

Comment: As of December 2023, "Support for unique index on existing collections with data is available in preview. This feature can be enabled for your database account by enabling the 'EnableUniqueIndexReIndex' capability.": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/indexing#indexing-all-properties